# ¿Django: como obtener option value desde clase createview usando un form?

Tags: python, django

Estoy usando CreateView para crear objetos, pero a la vez necesito actualizar otro model con la data de un select, pero obteniendo el `value`:

views.py:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class BitacoraCreateView(CreateView):
     form_class = BitacoraForm
     template_name = 'bitacora.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        kilometrajeform = form.cleaned_data['kilometraje_llegada']
        hodometroform = form.cleaned_data['hodometro_llegada']
        maquinaform = //get value option para obtener "id" de objeto maquina
        maquina = Maquina.objects.get(id=maquinaform)
        maquina.kilometraje = kilometrajeform
        maquina.hodometro = hodometroform
        maquina.save()
        return super(BitacoraCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("bitacora_list")
```

models.py:

```
class Bitacora(models.Model):
    compania = models.ForeignKey(Compania)
    maquina =   ChainedForeignKey(Maquina,chained_field="compania",chained_model_field="compania")
    #otros campos
```

forms.py

```
class BitacoraForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bitacora
        fields = ['compania','maquina', 'conductor', 'cliente', 'direccion', 'fecha',
              'hora_salida','hora_llegada','clave','kilometraje_salida',
              'kilometraje_llegada','hodometro_salida','hodometro_llegada','observciones']
        widgets = {
            'compania': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'maquina': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'conductor': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'cliente': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'direccion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'fecha': forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'fecha', 'class': 'date-picker form-control'}),
            'hora_salida': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'hora_llegada': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'clave': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'kilometraje_salida': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'pattern': '[0-9]*'}),
            'kilometraje_llegada': forms.TextInput( attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'pattern': '[0-9]*'}),
            'hodometro_salida': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'pattern': '[0-9]*'}),
            'hodometro_llegada': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'pattern': '[0-9]*'}),
            'observciones': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'height: 90px;'}),
        }
```

Sé que con una función pasando el parametro `request` puedo obtenerlo con `request.post['select_name']`, pero con class based view nosé como hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostrar el contenido de tu `BitacoraForm`?

Comment: Editado mostrando lo solicitado, omití algunos campos del form como el kilometraje y el hodometro pero se entiende...

Comment: ¿De dónde salen `kilometraje_llegada` y `hodometro_llegada`? No los veo en tu `fields` del formulario. Por otro lado, ¿no funciona simplemente haciendo `form.cleaned_data['maquina']`?

Comment: El tema es que si hago: `maquinaform= form.cleaned_data['maquina']'` me trae el nombre y no el value que es el id que necesito.

Comment: bueno, ahora actualicé el `BitacoraForm` completo.

Comment: muestra tus modelos... sobretodo el modelo de `Bitacora`

Comment: @GermanAlzate lo actualicé. Sé que con una función pasando el parametro `request` puedo obtenerlo con `request.post['select_name']`, pero con class based view nosé como hacerlo. Saludos

Comment: de donde es ese `ChainedForeignKey`??? me parece que el problema empieza por aqui.